# Jest mock ES6 module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

How can I mock an ES6 module import using Jest?
For example we have the following structure:

```js
// ../store.js
function getData(data) {
  return data / 3;
}
export { getData };
```

```js
// ../myModule.js
import { getData } from './store';

function myModule(param) {
  return getData(param) * 4;
}

export { myModule };
```

```js
// ./myModule.test.js
import { myModule ] from '../myModule';

test('2 x 4 equal 8', () => {
  expect(getData(6)).toBe(8);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To mock ES2015 modules, your jest config needs to use babel to convert the modules first.

You'll want to `yarn add --dev babel-jest babel-preset-env`

and then your package.json should look something like this:

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.css$"
    ]
  }
```

Secondly, in your `.babelrc` you need to specify your environment for `test` like so:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", "react"]
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [["env"], "react"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [["env"], "react"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env"], "react"]
    }
  }
}
```

Once that's done, you can mock a module. For example, make a file called `__mocks__/store.js` (where the mocks folder is in the same level as your `store.js` file. Inside of your mocks file, you can do something like

```
const getData = () => return 42;
export { getData };
```

and in your `myModule.test.js` you need this line:
`jest.mock('./store');`

If you want, you can see a working example from one of my repositories here:
https://github.com/AnilRedshift/linkedINonymous/

Answer (score 0):

If you want make automated test with jest, you have to include before the test/describe the next call

`jest.mock('../myModule');`

It returns void result from all functions.

Other alternative is mock mixed:

```
const mock: any = jest.genMockFromModule('../myModule'); 
mock.getData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(6);
```

The call to method getData returns 6.