# Mocking es6 module with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am writing a test for a function `sendEmail` that uses npm package `@sendgrid/mail`. I'd like to mock `@sendgrid/mail` in my function and then make assertions on the mocked functions, but for some reason I can't get my code to use the mocked version. The version imported in the test is always the real one, and the actual module is used in my `sendEmail`.

Based on the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) it seems like

```js
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
import { sendEmail } from './functions.js';

jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail');
describe('functions.js', () => {
  test('email subject is generated correctly', async () => {
    console.log(sgMail);

    await sendEmail('test');
    // expect(sgMail.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hi');
  });
});
```

I have tried:

- providing factory functions
- using manual mocks in `__mocks__` instead.
- Looking at several examples on [github](https://github.com/search?q=jest.mock%28%27%40sendgrid%2Fmail&type=code),nothing seems too far from what I am doing.
- adding  `testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-node',` like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816572/4541769
- I have even tried random babel voodoo as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883959/jest-mock-es6-module) of dubious age to be relevant,
- as well as the `__esModule: true,` property which doesn't seem to be required in my case as I'm not using both default and named modules.

I don't think this is a sendgrid issue as I have the same problem with Google secret manager. Is there something in my configuration I'm missing? I know I've written similar tests before, but can't spot the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest mock sendgrid send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653015/jest-mock-sendgrid-send-email)

Comment: @kamran Unfortunately not, which has led me think it might be related to es6 vs require

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was hoisting, and the understandably evolving support for jest and es6. a solution using `jest.unstable_mockModule` and `await import(...` worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71044616/4541769